# Python: combine list with lists of list while preserving lists elements

Tags: python

Is there a syntactically short way of doing this?

```
['a','b','c'] and [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]] -> [['a', [1,2]], ['b', [1]], ['c',[1,2,3]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c'] 
>>> b = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]]
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [1]), ('c', [1, 2, 3])]
```

If you really want the elements to be list instead of tuples, you can do as well, like this:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(a,b)]
[['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [1]], ['c', [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: This is actually a first answer first score question ^^)

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 Sure, why not? There's even [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) for being first and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this : 
    [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]

A shorter version : map(list,zip(a,b))

This will explain things :

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]]
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> c
[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [1]), ('c', [1, 2, 3])]
>>> d = [list(x) for x in c]
>>> d
[['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [1]], ['c', [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

zip+list+map

```
result = map(list,zip(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `enumerate` if the lists are the same size:

```
l1  = ['a','b','c']
l2 = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]]
[[ele,l2[ind]]for ind, ele in enumerate(l1)]
[['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [1]], ['c', [1, 2, 3]]]
```

If you have different size lists you can use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

```
l1  = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]]

from itertools import izip_longest
print [list(x) for x in izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue="No data")]
[['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [1]], ['c', [1, 2, 3]], ['d', 'No data']]
```